# One wireless mouse+keybard with 2 receivers in 2 laptops

Tags: wireless-networking

I have bought a Seenda wireless mouse+keyboard with a receiver. The receiver is plugged into a Linux laptop.

Now there is another laptop is coming (Mac) which I will need to use as well.

Is there any way to have 2 receivers (each for one laptop) to be used with the same mouse+keyboard.

I have bought another Seenda wireless mouse (Seenda, but different product) with a receiver, but unfortunately it does not listen for the mouse+keyboard pair.

Thought may be there is some way to re-program the receiver. It uses the same 2.4 frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The receiver in the computer (A) has to pair with the Keyboard / Mouse combination being used.

A different receiver in a different computer (B) will not see the keyboard.  Businesses using all kinds of these devices use this concept to prevent interference.

So in your case, the Keyboard / Mouse combination would have to be un-paired from (A) and paired to (B).

Commercial receivers for this use are not programmable in this respect.

So you need a Keyboard / Mouse combination for each computer.

I have long client experience with these devices.